# PPT generator using SOLID principles

Tags: php, object-oriented

I want to use SOLID more and more but still learning, I'm improving a PPT generator and would like your help applying SOLID principles in it.

- That generator should print two photos per slide, first one to the left, second to the right;
- If the last photo is a left photo, it should be placed in center;
- Each photo has a text right below it;
- I'll use a third party PPT lib to do the low level stuff.

This is what I came up with, a little bit abstracted just to pass the idea, the sample is in PHP but I'll accept answers in any programming language:

```
class Controller 
{
    $ppt = new Ppt(Ppt::DEFAULT_RESOLUTION, $background, $header, $footer);

    $ppt->writeSlides($photoCollection);

    $pptFile = $ppt->saveToFile();

    $ppt->deleteLocalTemporaryFiles();

    readfile($pptFile);
    unlink($pptFile);
}

class Ppt extends thirdPartyPptLib
{
    const DEFAULT_RESOLUTION = 'x';

    private $resolution;
    private $background;
    private $header;
    private $footer;

    public function __construct($resolution = null, $background = null, $header = null, $footer = null)
    {
        $this->resolution = $resolution;
        $this->background = $background;
        $this->header     = $header;
        $this->footer     = $footer;
    }

    public function writeSlides(\Traversable $photoCollection)
    {
        $i     = 0;
        $count = count($photoCollection);

        foreach ($photoCollection as $photoInfo) {
            $photoToLeft = $i % 2 == 0;
            $isLastPhoto = $i == ($count - 1);

            if ($isLastPhoto) {
                $slide = $this->newSlide();    
                $slide->addCenterPhotoInfo($photoInfo);    

            } else if ($photoToLeft) {
                $slide = $this->newSlide();    
                $slide->addLeftPhotoInfo($photoInfo);    

            } else {
                $slide->addRightPhotoInfo($photoInfo);    
            }       

            $i++;            
        }
    }

    private function newSlide()
    {
        $slide = parent->newSlide();

        if ($this->hasBackground()) {
            $slide->setBackground();
        }

        if ($this->hasHeader()) {
            $slide->setHeader();
        }

        if ($this->hasFooter()) {
            $slide->setFooter();
        }       

        return $slide;
    }
}

class Slide extends thirdPartyPptLibSlide
{
    public function addLeftPhotoInfo($photoInfo)
    {
        $this->addLeftPhoto($photoInfo->getPhoto());
        $this->addUnderlyingText($photoInfo->getText());
    }

    // functions addRightPhotoInfo and addCenterPhotoInfo very similar
}
```

Should I separate it more into different classes? Or methods? Should I create Interfaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the overloading of properties from constructor.
This way you can improve the code maintaning and readability.

An example of improvement:

```
class Style {
    // Properties here    
}

class Ppt {
    public function __construct(Style $style) {
    }
}
```

Now you pass just the object of style with all the needed properties.